# Complexity of Pascals formula

Tags: complexity-theory

I have seen this problem and I couldn't solve it
the problem is finding the complexity of C(m,n) = C(m-1, n-1) + C(m, n-1)   ( Pascal's formula )
Its an iterated formula but with two variable, I have no idea to solve this
I would b happy for your help... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the 2D representation of this formula you get to sum numbers that cover the "area" of a triangle when given its "height", so the complexity would be o(n^2) if calculated directly from the formula.

Idk if what I just said makes sense at all to you but you can also think of expressing the complexity of each iteration of the formula for a fixed n, which will give you linear complexity, multiplied by the linear complexity over n you should still get o(n^2)

This line of thought seems to match what they demonstrate here:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pascal-triangle/